# 'not found: type' error

Tags: scala

I'm reading 'Programming in scala' and in one of the example when I try to compile it in Eclipse I receive error : 'not found: type ChecksumAccumulator' The type is declared as below. Is the code below correct ?

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map

object ChecksumAccumulator {

  private val cache = Map[String, Int]()

  def calculate(s: String): Int = 
    if(cache.contains(s))
      cache(s)
    else {
      val acc = new ChecksumAccumulator
      for(c <- s)
        acc.add(c.toBye)
      val cs = acc.checksum()
      cache += (s -> cs)
      cs
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just the companion object—to create an instance (the `new ChecksumAccumulator` line here) you also need the class definition from a few pages earlier in the book (Listing 4.1).

Comment: @Travis Brown yep that was it, don't tell me you recalled the page from reading the book once :) if put comment into an answer ill accept it.

Comment: Nope—just remembered the example and Google did the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [*Programming in Scala*](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/classes-and-objects.html):

> The singleton object in this figure is named `ChecksumAccumulator`,
>   the same name as the class in the previous example. When a singleton
>   object shares the same name with a class, it is called that class's
>   companion object. You must define both the class and its companion
>   object in the same source file. The class is called the companion
>   class of the singleton object.

If you try to compile this code alone, without the `ChecksumAccumulator` class, you'll get a compiler error because you can't create an instance of a singleton object with `new`. 
The book does a great job of explaining how companion objects and classes work together, and since you're already reading it I won't bother adding any further summary here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the book class is defined too early and later in the file **ChecksumAccumulator.scala** class definition is not there. For a beginner it is enough to mislead and will get stuck. This must be the complete code for the two files.

In **ChecksumAccumulator.scala**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Map
class ChecksumAccumulator {
 private
 var sum = 0
 def add(b: Byte) {
  sum += b
 }
 def checksum(): Int = ~(sum & 0xFF) + 1
}
object ChecksumAccumulator {
 private val cache = Map[String, Int]()
 def calculate(s: String): Int =
  if (cache.contains(s))
   cache(s)
  else {
   val acc = new ChecksumAccumulator
   for (c < -s)
    acc.add(c.toByte)
   val cs = acc.checksum()
   cache += (s -> cs)
   cs
  }
}
```

In **Summer.scala**

```
import ChecksumAccumulator.calculate
object Summer {
 def main(args: Array[String]) {
  for (arg < -args)
   println(arg + ": " + calculate(arg))
 }
}
```

Then you can compile using.

```
scalac ChecksumAccumulator.scala Summer.scala
```

Then run the example with

```
scala Summer of love
```

Which will give you the below output:

```
of: -213
love: -182
```